# Overlay two density plots in plotly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I have a dataset which contains two columns.

Each row is a user with `frequency` (1~31, shows how frequently a user plays a game monthly) and `is_consumed`(0,1 whether the user ever consumed in the game).

I want to draw two density plots for `frequency` separated by the value of `is_consumed`.

I finished it in ggplot2 but I want to use plotly.
`ggplot2 code:`

```
p2 <- p_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(frequency, fill = is_consumed)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) 
p2
```

Output

Red is the density plot of `is_consumed == 1`. Green is `is_consumed == 0`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a cool function in the plotly library called `ggplotly()` that converts a ggplot object into a plotly object: https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_density/

So you could do:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

p_plot <- data.frame(frequency = c(rnorm(31, 1), rnorm(31)),
                     is_consumed = factor(round(runif(62))))
p2 <- p_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(frequency, fill = is_consumed)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)     
ggplotly(p2)
```